# switching between windows using chrome webdriver is not working

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python and webscraping, I want to retrieve some information on a website but some of the information is displayed on a popup window. The problem I'm having now is switching from the main page to the popup window to get the html and then switch back to the main page. 
In order words after getting some information from page A, i need to switch to this link

```
 https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Refs/cage.aspx?Cage=0VET6
```

to obtain the company name and then switch back to page A

this a section of the code that I have

```
for batch in containers:

                            try:
                                print(" ")

                                awardid = batch.find('a', text=True).text
                                ordernumber = batch.find_all('span')[1].text
                                cagecode = batch.find_all('span')[6].text


                                price = batch.find_all('span')[7].text
                                date = batch.find_all('span')[8].text
                                NSN = batch.find_all('span')[10].text
                                Nomenclature= batch.find_all('span')[11].text
                                purchasereq = batch.find_all('span')[12].text

                                if cagecode :
                                    cagelink = 'https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Refs/cage.aspx?Cage='+cagecode

                                    #switch to pop-up window
                                    try:

                                        driver.execute_script("window.open("+cagelink+",'new window')")
                                    except Exception as e:

                                        print("error from driver ", str(e))
                                        continue

                                    try:
                                        cagesoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

                                        bodycontainer = cagesoup.find("tbody")
                                        print('cage code body',bodycontainer)
                                    except Exception as e:

                                        print("error from soup ", str(e))
                                        continue

                            except Exception as e:
                                print(colorama.Fore.MAGENTA + "award error.."+ str(e) )
                                # print(container1)

                                continue

                    except Exception as e:
                        continue
```

the problem I have now is that i am getting an error that I am missing a ) at the end of the argument here

```
    driver.execute_script("window.open("+cagelink+",'new window')")
```

and when I try to remove the cagelink and use

```
        https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Refs/cage.aspx?Cage=0VET6
```

it display none. what am I doing wrongly and how can I switch between the windows to obtain the company name on the popup window?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's for sure incorrect is the argument you are passing to the js method - it is not quoted, e.g. not treated as string. This line here:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open("+cagelink+",'new window')")
```

Should be:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('"+cagelink+"','new window')")
```

*Even more readable would be to use string formatting:*

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('{}','new window')".format(cagelink))
```

Comment: ok the string formating works but this line of code                     bodycontainer = cagesoup.find("tbody") that is suppose to get the body tage of the newly opened window is instead retrieving the tag of the main page. how can i switch the driver between both?

Comment: That is a separate question, answered numerous times on SO - please search for it.